# Combinational implementation of hashing algorithms

Tags: hash, vhdl, verilog

I am working on a project that requires the use of combinational implementations of hashing algorithms. VHDL/Verilog are the target languages, since I hope to work on an FPGA. I've done some searching and I've come across the RFC specs for MD5 and SHA1, but I can't seem to find a combinational (avoid clocks please) implementation in VHDL/Verilog anywhere. Do you know of any? The hashing algorithm itself is immaterial as long as it is at least as strong as MD1.

Comment: Does it need to be purely combinational because you have an asynchronous design?

Comment: It needs to be purely combinational because I would like the implementation to have only lookup tables in the synthesized version of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with an implementation of either MD5 or SHA1 written in C. Then manually translate each step in the algorithm to a step in a flowchart. Every arithmetic or logical operation in the C code becomes a combinational logic operation (gates). The source and destination variables in the C code become input and output ports on your hardware design. Temporary variables in the C code become the names of internal nets connecting your combinational logic blocks.

Theoretically, it should be possible to create a purely combinational implementation of these algorithms. Practically, you might find that it requires too many hardware resources (adders, multipliers, etc.) and that you will need to reuse resources. As soon as you need to reuse resources, you need to introduce some intermediate registers and then your output will not be valid for a certain number of clock cycles.

Comment: I think I saw a project on the internet that implements SHA1 that way. This is a good idea... I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's an interestingly wacky requirement!

I think you'll struggle to find one out there - hashing is usually required to be high-throughput, which tends to mean lots of pipelining and a fast clock and hence registers.

It shouldn't be too hard to write though:

- write modules/entities for the various "mixing" stages used in the algorithm
- create a round entity which puts the mixing entities in the right order
- use a `for`..`generate` loop (or its Verilog equivalent) to create all the rounds you need.

Comment: True... I think I'll be converting some C code to VHDL/Verilog directly from within the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check [www.opencores.org/projects](http://www.opencores.org/projects)
It has many cryptographic cores available, with source to study.